# Can't create a sql connection due to the fact that it won't rcognize the data source keyword

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

Hello I'm trying to run a simple sql command on a DB from MS VS C# 2010 and I have encountered a error I have never seen before the relevant code is:

```
  SqlConnection comCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\\programming\\C#workspace\\Projects\\Examen\\Examen\\Companie.mdf;Initial Catalog=Proiect;Integrated Security=True"); 

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

  cmd.CommandText =  "UPDATE Proiect SET Buget = Buget + 500 WHERE (Buget > 0)";

  cmd.Connection = comCon;                                                      
  comCon.Open();
  Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
  comCon.Close();
```

And the error is  Keyword not supported: 'data source'

The main problem is that I'm not used to creating these sqlconnections by hand so please tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: connection strings dont point to physical files , rather Data Source points to DB Engine Instance name.check this link 'http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008'

Comment: Thank this has helped but now it gives me this error  Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\George\Desktop\programming\C#workspace\Projects\Examen\Examen\Companie.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\George\Desktop\programming\C#workspace\Projects\Examen\Examen\Companie.mdf' as database 'Companie'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong structure. To attach a *database* file, you need to use the following structure:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = 
    "Server=DatabaseServerName;AttachDbFilename=d:\Database\Database.mdf;
     Database=DatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=Yes";
```

You need to have the right permissions on both the target *file* and *database server* to attach the *databse* and establish the connection.

Comment: @Bronze_Hero: You do not have access permissions for the current windows user on the file you are trying to attach ...

Comment: Then how would I obtain them? This is my computer and I just created a simple database

Comment: @Bronze_Hero: Since that is your computer and I guess you are using an administrator account, I guess the problem may be something else. How have you created this database? Have you used sql server management studio ?

Comment: No I created it form C# add new Item database

Comment: @Bronze_Hero: Well, try to obtain the connection string by doing the following: from the server explorer panel, right click the connection and select properties. The properties panel will be activated. Use the value in the Connection String field...

Comment: Thank you I've already did that,but to no avail, it's become obvious that the error lies in the method I created the db,I will start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

If it's not an ASP.NET application don't use the DataDirectory syntax and just use the full c:... path.